# Something wrong with double

Tags: sqlite

What is wrong?

```
sqlite> select latitude from company where company_id=48452;    
55.7898788452149    
select count(*) from company where latitude=55.7898788452149;
0
```

I can not really get it.

Comment: This is the nature of finite precision representation. It's the same reason in finite precision decimal, "2/3" will end with a 7 but "1/3 + 1/3" will end with a 6. Basically, don't compare for equality. Compare for "sufficiently close". (For example, for this query, maybe greater than 55.7898788 and less than 55.7898789.)

Comment: you need to learn about floating point - this is your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3270597/1726419

Comment: Another possibility is to use strings for longitudes and latitudes.